# How to find changes of a file across all branches in a Git repository?

Tags: git

In a Git repository I'm working with we have one main branch and several feature branches which different teams are working with. In some cases I would like to know if anybody else is working with a specified file/directory. Is there a way to check this in Git, without having to manually run the check for each feature branch?

Another way to put it is that I want to find out if my modifications to a specific file/directory can create merge conflicts with any other branch.

So technically I think I would like to know if there are any commits which contains changes to a specific file/folder and that are reachable from any ref (e.g. a feature branch) but not reachable from a specific rev (e.g. the main branch).

Desired output would be branch names and/or commit hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log --all ^master -- path/to/directory/*
```

would produce a commit list of everything that has impacted said directory but is yet unknown to `master`.

---

Then, to map that with branches, you can check specific commits to know where they're already present with

```
git branch -a --contains <commitHash>
```

It'll output every branch having this commit in its history.

Comment: Couldn't get the log command to work at first but finally I realised that a caret is an escape character in the Windows Command Prompt \*facepalm\*

Comment: @LoPoBo Haha yes, well done since you did spot it eventually. And I admit I didn't think of considering the possibility, in order to adress it preemptively. Duly noted.